# Partial fraction decomposition with a 3rd degree numerator

Tags: partial-fractions

I have the following function to decompose using PFD:

$H(x) = \frac{x^3 + 4x^2 - 11x - 48}{x^3 + 6x^2 + 3x - 10}$

The poles are $1$, $-2$ and $-5$ so I tried to do it this way: finding $a$, $b$ and $c$ such as:

$H(x) = \frac{a}{x-1} + \frac{b}{x+2} + \frac{c}{x+5}$

But it didn't give me a correct result. Doing it that way gives me $(a,b,c) = (-3, 2, -1) $

Is there a specific form of numerator to introduce here? Thanks.

Comment: Apply polynomial long division first

Comment: Divide first to reduce the degree of the numerator to strictly less than the degree of the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the degree of the numerator is $\geq$ to the degree of the denominator you should first divide them. Hence
$$\frac{x^3 + 4x^2 - 11x - 48}{x^3 + 6x^2 + 3x - 10}=1-\frac{2x^2 + 14x + 38}{x^3 + 6x^2 + 3x - 10}=1+\frac{a}{x-1} + \frac{b}{x+2} + \frac{c}{x+5}$$
for some real constants $a$, $b$, $c$ (the same that you already found by using the residue method!).

Comment: How do you proceed with the polynomial division?

Comment: In this case the have the same degree and the same principal term so just subtract the denominator to the numerator. In general see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 0):

for your control: it is $$1+2\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-1}- \left( x+5 \right) ^{-1}-3\, \left( x-
1 \right) ^{-1}
$$

Comment: It  seems (based on comparing your result to the one in the OP) that the OP may simply have gotten $a,b,c$ rearranged.  It would certainly help to give details for how you arrived at the above.